# How to updateMany many times within one function? MONGODB - Shell

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-shell, mongodb-schema

As the question suggests, I have multiple columns which I would like to rename via shell.

```
db.Hours.updateMany(
  {},
  {"$rename" : {"season" : "Season"}},
)
db.Hours.updateMany(
  {},
  {"$rename" :{"yr" : "Year"}}
)
db.Hours.updateMany(
  {},
  {"$rename" : {"cnt" : "TotalRiders"}}
)
```

Above is a snippet of the code, I believe it could be done by passing these arguements to one function. Is that possible? Something like below.

```
db.Hours."FUNCTION"(
{ { {}, {"$rename : { " " : " "}}},
  { {}, {"$rename : { " " : " "}}}....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$rename` operator takes an object of containing `oldName:newName` fields.

You can pass more than one, like:

```
db.Hours.updateMany(
  {},
  {"$rename" : {"season" : "Season",
                "yr" : "Year",
                "cnt" : "TotalRiders"}}
)
```

Comment: How would you do this for a situation where ```db.Hours.updateMany(
  {"Season" : "1"}, { "$set" : { "Season" : "Spring"}}
)

db.Hours.updateMany(
  {"Season" : "2"}, { "$set" : { "Season" : "Summer"}}
)```

Comment: not sure if you got the notification @joe